# UiPath: How to set default values to a String[] variable

Tags: c#, uipath-studio

I have an exception when I'm trying to launch my workflow. It cames from my array declaration where I apparently don't have the right syntax.

My syntax really looks like the one used in the UiPath tuto I follow :

The tuto syntax: [image: The array from the tuto]

My syntax: [image: My array]

I don't understand how I'm supposed to write the default values for a simple array of strings...

I'm only trying to pass the values in a Write Line activity, but this shows up when compiling: [image: exception]

If anyone can help, I'm stuck... Thanks

--- EDIT ---

The exception message is the following one:

Message: Compilation failure:

; expected Unvalid expression terms ',' ... many times...

The full results are stored in the Data property of this exception. Correct the errors of the source, then retry the load.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post so you have it in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I did not instantiate the array with `new String[]` at the beginning. I suppose that the tutos are written using VB and not C#, which can explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

your declaration is correct maybe you have error in the loop here is a working example

[image]

Comment: Well, I just solved my problem, but if this works for you I don't understand why it didn't for me...
I added `new String[]` before the values list and it is working now. Are you using C# or VB language?

Comment: sometimes the project dependencies are not working properly and you need to restart the studio or to delete and retype a value in the assign activity ….. In my work I am using .NET methods